# Matplotlib plot not updating

Tags: python, matplotlib, serial-port, real-time

I have a process to get data from the serial port that comes in every 10ms-10sec.  If I update the plot directly from the serial process, the GUI freezes in-between updates.   I've seen other question/answers that suggest using FuncAnimation/ion/pause, however, I have a problem on how to get the data from the serial process to the matplotlib class that's doing the drawing.. even after enabling FuncAnimation, I don't see the update function getting called.

I'm not sure if there's a better (pythonic) way of doing all this or if the use of threads would be more appropriate. And if passing queue data is not a good idea, how else can I update the plot from the serial to avoid the "Not Responding" freeze that happens in between updates?

```
from time import time, sleep  
from multiprocessing import Queue as  mpQueue
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

global ani   # **Must be assigned to a global variable****

class PlotClass:
    # Create *STATIC LOCAL* instances accessible across class functions
    fig = None
    ax = None
    line1 = None
    q = None
    x_list_vec = []
    y1_list_vec = [] 

    def __init__(self, qdata ):    
        # Save handle to Queue
        self.q = qdata

        # this is the call to matplotlib that allows dynamic plotting
        plt.ion()

        # Setup Figure with 'size' number of elements
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)    

        # Create a list variable to the animation 
        self.line1, = self.ax.plot(self.x_list_vec, self.y1_list_vec, marker = 'o', label='y1', color='r')        

        #Show a starting plot
        plt.ion()
        plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
        plt.title('Title: Hello World')
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
        plt.show()

    def update(self, frame_num , user_arg1, user_arg2):     #<<<< Never Executes!!!
        print("Update")
        while self.q.empty() is False:
            print ("Got Data!")   
            print ( self.q.get() )

        #Dummy Draw
        self.line1.set_data(0, 6)

        #Must return list when blit=True        
        return self.line1, 

    # Override the run function of Thread class
    def run(self):
        # **Must be assigned to a global variable!****
        global ani  
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=self.fig, func=self.update, fargs=["Hi", 2], interval=0.1, blit=True, repeat=False) 
        print ("FuncAnimation")   

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:      
        # Shared Memory
        q = mpQueue()

        # Start Plotter
        mpInst = PlotClass( q )
        mpInst.run()

        # Push Data to Plotter
        while True:
            q.put(1)
            sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Keyboard Interrupt!")
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I've updated the code as to not need any serial traffic to reproduce the issue.   Just manually putting data in a queue, and trying to get it on the other side.   The PlotClass update (assuming it's getting called) never shows any data in the queue.

Comment: The matplotlib examples contain [code](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/animation/strip_chart.html) how to integrate a stream of data into your matplotlib animation.